# Remove auto added trailing forward slash in asp.net mvc img src

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to load a asp.net mvc 4 page with images in jpg extension as the img src. When requesting the images, it's automatically adding a forward slash to the url parameter resulting in a 400 (bad request) from server. How can I get around this?

Example (x.ImageUrl is definitely a string without the trailing slash):

```
@foreach (var x in Model.List)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src=@x.ImageUrl/></td>
            <td><a href="@x.ItemUrl">@x.Title</a></td>
            <td>@x.Price</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

In view images are requested like this:
    [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51a6DHwbx-L.*AA160*.jpg/](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51a6DHwbx-L._AA160_.jpg/)

Comment: post your code. The view and the output html

Answer (score 0):

By placing @x.ImageUrl in quotes, the image loaded properly without slash.